# Android how to get a String from the TextView to a String

Tags: java, android, string

I know how to take integer value to string like

```
String s = st.getText().toString(0;
```

but my question is how we will take for a character... suppose the value ofa textView txt1 = 'A' so how we will take the value to a string str1..

```
String str1 = txt1.getText().toString();
```

is it correct....?

Comment: Yes this will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextView.getText() return `java.lang.CharSequence` , and ideally you should be able to apply `toString()` to get the String value.  But, however,

from `CharSequence` [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html)

> This interface does not refine the general contracts of the equals and
>   hashCode methods. The result of comparing two objects that implement
>   CharSequence is therefore, in general, undefined. Each object may be
>   implemented by a different class, and there is no guarantee that each
>   class will be capable of testing its instances for equality with those
>   of the other. It is therefore inappropriate to use arbitrary
>   CharSequence instances as elements in a set or as keys in a map.

CharSequence is an interface( though toString() appears as declared), it should work provided the CharSequence implementer did their job properly. To avoid any suprises, you can try a different approch

```
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(charSequence.length());
sb.append(charSequence);
return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String str1 = txt1.getText().toString();
```

Yes. It's the right answer to get the string value from string .

Answer (score 1):

If `getText()` already returns a `String`, your job is already done for you. It's a string to begin with.

If you absolutely must create a `String` from a single `char` value, you can do so with the constructor that takes a `char[]` as an argument: `new String(new char[] {value})`.

If, as Satheesh stated above, it returns a `CharSequence`, there is also a `String` constructor that takes that as a parameter. Thus, it may be best to declare a `new String(txt1.getText())` rather than relying on the implementation of the returned `CharSequence`'s `toString()` method.